# GNU Makefile Multiple rules in multiple targets

Tags: makefile, gnu

I am doing a nasm project, and I need to execute the *ej* and use as a parameter the *ex*.asm . I tried searching through [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) how can I pick one by one the parameter. My solution has been writing *ex1_* and *ex2_*, but I want to put those inside the *$(ex)* dependency, so I don't have to replicate multiple times the same code. Is there any way?

Thank you in advance

The code:

```
ej = ej1_gen ej2_gen
ex = ex1     ex2

# -----------------------------------------------
all: $(ej) $(ex)
exs: ex1_ ex2_ 
# -----------------------------------------------

$(ex): exs
    nasm -g -o $@.o -f elf32 $@.asm
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -m32 -o $@ $@.o alfalib.o

ex1_:
    ./ej1_gen ex1.asm
ex2_:
    ./ej2_gen ex2.asm
```

Comment: So `ex1.asm` and `ex2.asm` are generated files?  With different programs `ej1_gen` and `ej2_gen` that generate them?  And do those code generator programs have any inputs that need to be accounted for?

Comment: *_gen receive the name of the file where the nasm code of the ex have to be. So it doesn't have to be necessarily ex1.asm and ex2.asm, but they have to follow the same structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read the question, you have programs or scripts `ej1_gen` and `ej2_jen` in the project, serving to generate the wanted assembly sources.  They each take the name of the output file as a command-line argument.  Parts of this answer would need to be adjusted if that's a misinterpretation.

---

Rules to describe how to build the assembly files should designate the resulting assembly file(s) as the target. Also, supposing that the code-generator programs are part of the project, they should be designated as prerequisites, since changing those could cause them to produce different outputs.  Any configuration files or similar that they read to inform their results should also be named as prerequisites (not shown).  That leads to rules something like this:

```
ex1.asm: ej1_gen
    ./ej1_gen $@

ex2.asm: ej2_gen
    ./ej2_gen $@
```

It sounds like you may be asking for a way to express that via just one rule covering both, but I would not do so in this case.  I don't think you get any clearer than the above, even if there are more than two assembly files to generate.  It might be different if the same code generator program were being used, with different options, to generate all the assembly files, or perhaps if the generator name could be derived more directly from the target name.

With those rules in place, you can write a generic suffix rule or pattern rule to assemble the resulting files.  Since you tag [gnu], I'll assume that a pattern rule is acceptable:

```
%.o: %.asm
    nasm -g -o $@ -f elf32 $<
```

And you can take a similar approach to expressing a link rule:

```
%: %.o alfalib.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -m32 -o $@ $^
```

With that, you should be able to get rid of the `ej` variable and the `exs` target, too, leaving

```
all: $(ex)
```

as the only other rule (and it should still appear first in the file, as it does now).

Comment: I wanted ex1_ and ex2_ yo be generated with something similar to $* or % because I only put in here 2, but I have near 40 of them, so I thought there would be an easier way and not write them one by one. But if you recommend me this, I'll do it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @SugarG.García, If each .asm file has its own dedicated generator program, and the naming pattern is and must remain as shown in the question, then yes, this is what I recommend, even for 40 .asm files.  But note that it is only for that step that you have so many rules.  This gives you just one rule that serves for assembling all the files, and one that serves for linking them.